# Elixir - pass partial output through pipe operator

Tags: elixir

When using the pipe operator in Elixir, is it possible to be selective/specific about the output that is passed from the first function to the second?

For example, I'm processing a map in three steps - I need to drop two keys, update the value of a different key, and finally pop another key, whose value I need to use later on in my code. Here's an illustration of what I'd ideally be able to achieve:

```
for r <- records do
  {scope, record} = 
    Map.drop(r, [:__struct__, :__meta__])
    |> Map.get_and_update(:id, fn current_value -> 
      {current_value, String.replace(current_value, "join", "scope", global: false)}
    end)
    |> Map.pop(:user_id)

  # SOME OTHER STUFF...

end
```

So that'd drop the `:__struct__` and `:__meta__` keys, update the value of the `:id` key by replacing the word "join" with "scope", and then pop the `:user_id` key off, leaving me with `{scope, record}`, where `scope` is the value of the popped key and `record` is the modified map. The code, as is, does not work, of course.

Here's a piece of sample data:

```
records = [
  %{__struct__: "foo", __meta__: "bar", id: "resource_join:1234", user_id: "user:1234"},
  %{__struct__: "foo", __meta__: "bar", id: "resources_join:5678", user_id: "user:5678"},
]
```

The first step in this process works, because `drop/2` returns just the modified map, which is the correct input for the first parameter to `get_and_update/3`. However, `get_and_update/3` returns a tuple where the first value is the value that that the function replaced and the second value is the modified map. This is where the pipe chain fails, because `pop/2` expects a map as the first argument, and here it's receiving a tuple.

Is there a way that I can control the output of `get_and_update/3` so that only the second value from the returned tuple is passed through the pipe to `pop/2`? I've been able to get the output that I need by breaking this chain up into several pieces, but if it were at all possible to chain these together, I'd like to.

Comment: Consider including data example, so anyone could run your code in console

Comment: Have you looked into using [with](http://learningelixir.joekain.com/learning-elixir-with/) in combination of what you have there?

Comment: Do you mean like adding `|> elem(1)` before `|> Map.pop(...)`? There's also `Map.update` if you don't care about the old value in `Map.get_and_update`.

Comment: @Dogbert right on, thanks for pointing out `elem()` - didn't know about that. I'll probably end up going with `update()`, but `elem()` technically answers my question.

Comment: @denis.peplin - good call, I've added a piece of sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to discard the first element of the tuple and only pass the second to `Map.pop`, you can add `|> elem(1)` to the pipeline:

```
|> Map.get_and_update(:id, fn current_value -> 
  {current_value, String.replace(current_value, "join", "scope", global: false)}
end)
|> elem(1)
|> Map.pop(:user_id)
```

Also, `Map.get_and_update` + `elem(1)` can be replaced with just `Map.update`, which doesn't return the old value of the key:

```
|> Map.update(fn current_value -> 
  String.replace(current_value, "join", "scope", global: false)
end)
|> Map.pop(:user_id)
```